# Spark - RelationalGroupedDataset vs. KeyvalueGroupedDataset? When should I use each of them?

Tags: apache-spark, aggregation, apache-spark-dataset

When grouping a `Dataset` in Spark, there are two methods: `groupBy` and `groupByKey[K]`.

`groupBy` returns `RelationalGroupedDataset`, while `groupByKey[K]` returns `KeyvalueGroupedDataset`.

**What are the differences between them?**

**Under what circumstances should I choose one over another?**

---

How come my question is a duplicate of those questions about "Dataset vs DataFrame"? I don't get it. It is obviously totally different things! My question is very specific not generic.

Comment: The title is a duplicate but the actual question is not. Its a shame this was marked as such.

Comment: This question should be re-opened, the answers mentioned don't cover the subject at all

Comment: This is a valid question and should be re-opened.